# update webpage as each of a number of mysql commands run

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run about 20 MYSQL commands via PHP, and as each one runs I want to print something on the screen with PHP, maybe just a "." or something as they progress...

is there a way to do this as they process without refreshing the page or whatever.

Comment: I'm very confused, what exactly is your question?

Comment: As far as I undestand you want something like a loading spinner? From my Point of view the best Option for this is using java Script with ajax which is calling your php script. So you show the loading Icon, than you call your php script with Ajax and on successful calling you can hide the loading Icon